# How can I optionally disable a drop of a jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list that has two items: projects and groups. Projects can go in groups. I have very simple code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/fgWEU/

How can I best disable groups from going inside groups? I had originally made different connected lists but dragging between things felt clunkier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this solution so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/fgWEU/4/

> .on ( 'sortupdate', function(e,ui) {
>
> ```
> if ( ui.item.hasClass('group') && ui.item.parent().hasClass( 'group-projects' ) ) {
>     ui.item.parent().closest( '.group' ).after( ui.item );
>
> }
>
>  });
> ```

It works, but I still wonder if there's something better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('group') && $(ui.item).parent().hasClass('group')) {
        $(this).sortable('cancel');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjVbC/

Comment: I can't use that since I actually have a droppable there and I filed this: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7640